# Compare 2 dynamically created matrix columns to get a difference

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a matrix set up with a Row Group called "company", a Column Group called "Year" and a value field that is a sum of charges through the year called revenue.  The column Group will end up having 2 columns in it that are provided through user input. The end results is a matrix that will look something like this:

```
         Year 1 | Year 2
Company:    $500    $250
Company2:   $750    $250
```

What I would like to do is add a column to the matrix that calculates the change from year 1 to year 2. Is there a way to do this within the matrix such as adding a new column with an expression that compares the 2 entries in the row or will I need to manipulate the SQL code to create a column that does this within the code?  To that end here is a view of the code for the dataset if that is the way I need to go:

```
SELECT
 company.cmp_id
,company.Company
,ChargeDetails.[Bill To ID]
,ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year]
,ChargeDetails.Revenue
FROM
ChargeDetails
LEFT OUTER JOIN company
ON ChargeDetails.[Bill To ID] = company.cmp_id
WHERE
ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year] = @DeliveryYear 
OR 
ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year] = @ComparisonYear2
ORDER BY ChargeDetails.[Delivery Year] DESC,ChargeDetails.Revenue DESC;`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following as the expression in the change column.

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Delivery_Year.Value=Parameters!DeliveryYear.Value,1,0)*Fields!Revenue.Value) -  sum(iif(Fields!Delivery_Year.Value=Parameters!ComparisonYear2.Value,1,0)* Fields!Revenue.Value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a column outside the Year group in header type `Change` or what you want to put, in the below cell use this expression:

```
=Sum(iif(Max(Fields!DeliveryYear.Value)=Fields!DeliveryYear.Value,Fields!Revenue.Value,0))-
Sum(iif(Min(Fields!DeliveryYear.Value)=Fields!DeliveryYear.Value,Fields!Revenue.Value,0))
```

> Note I am substracting the **min** year (1) revenue sum to the **max**
>   year (2) revenue sum.

In your example it will produce:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Company   | Year 1 | Year 2 | Change |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Company A | 500    | 250    | -250   |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

You can define *change* in many ways maybe in percentage or any other measure, this is only an example, learn what the above expression is doing in order to calculate the measure you need.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Add the matrix with this data arrangement.

[image]

The matrix looks like this one in preview:

[image]

Be sure you added the Change column outside the DeliveryYear group as shown in above image. Also check the fields names correspond to yours in the expression.

**EDIT 2:**

If Revenue has null values you can try this:

Try replace the null values at query level using T-SQL `ISNULL()` Function, change your query in this part as follows

```
,ISNULL(ChargeDetails.Revenue,0)
```

However if DeliveryYear has null values you may want to ignore that records, so try to exclude it in the where clause.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thank you for the help what I am essentially trying to measure is just the difference in sales from year 1 to year 2 for the companies we do business with, When using your code I get a #Error in the Change column

Comment: Hello, I have made all of the changes you suggested and have my matrix set up exactly as you do however I am getting #Error.
@alejandro zuleta

<img src="http://i.imgur.com/QfXUMkh.jpg">

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/QfXUMkh.jpg)
[link](http://i.imgur.com/H52tVSM.png)
[link](http://i.imgur.com/PEuKAFf.png)

@alejandro zuleta

Comment: Are you sure Change column is outside the Delivery_Year group? Select any cell in your matrix then add a image of your matrix at design time. Check the first image of my answer EDIT, you can see the groups cells division (gray and yelow line)

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/Y6wqm36.png)

The link shows the matrix and it does have the change column outside of the year.

Thanky ou for the help on this.

Comment: Does your dataset have **Revenue** or **DeliveryYear** `NULL` rows? A representative sample of your dataset could be useful.

Comment: Yes there are some rows with null values in it.

Comment: @Tom, check my EDIT 2.

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/LuFbDOd.jpg)

Here is a view of the results with edit 2 incorporated. So the only time an error isn't presented as the results is when one of the values is empty.  Also note this is after making the edit you suggested in edit2

Comment: @Tom, unfortunately I cannot guess what is your problem without check your data. It could be related to one or several conditions in your data: DeliveryYear with null values or not int data type, Revenue with null values  or unexpected values that could affect the expression behaviour. I've tried to recreate your errors without success.

Comment: I understand and have been going through the data looking for non int and null values and so far have not been able to really find anything substantial. If/when I find a solution I will post my answer.  Thank you for the help.